# Python - remove elements from array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matplotlib, scipy

I have an array called `a` and another array `b`. The array `a` is the main array where I store float data, and `b` is an array which contain some indexes belonging to `a`.

Example:

```
a = [1.3, 1.7, 18.4, 56.2, 82.2, 18.1, 81.9, 56.9, -274.45]
b = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

In this example `b` contains indexes of `a` from `0` to `7`.

What I'm trying to do in Python is to remove "duplicates", I mean to remove all indexes from `b` which have their similar value in `a`. For example, notice that there are pair `1.3` and `1.7`. Also, there are `18.4` and `18.1` etc. I want to find all these values and to write `-1` in all places in array `b` which has that value.

Output should be the following:

```
b = [0, -1, 2, 3, 4, -1, -1, -1]
```

I think it is obvious what I am trying to achieve. Here index `1` is replaced with `-1` because in `a` it represents `1.7` which has "pair" `1.3`. Also, last 3 indexes represents `18.1`, `81.9` and `56.9` which also have their "pairs" before, so they are replaced with `-1`.

Of course, I have a parameter `x` which represents how "similar" values are. So, here `x = 2` which mean that any 2 values which differ by `2` are similar.

**What have I tried?** I tried to use 2 nested for loops and a lot of unnecessary variables and my algorithm eats memory and performance. Is there an elegant `np`-ish way to achieve it?

Comment: How similar do two values have to be to be removed?

Comment: Why was the last elem removed, that was `-274.45`? What's that elem similar to?

Answer (score 5):

**Approach #1 :** Here's a vectorized approach using [`broadcasting`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/user/basics.broadcasting.html) and a bit memory intensive -

```
x = 2 # threshold that decides similarity
a_b = a[b]
mask = np.triu(np.abs(a_b[:,None]-a_b)<x,1).any(0)
b[mask[:len(b)]] = -1
```

Sample run -

```
In [95]: a = np.array([1.3, 1.7, 18.4, 56.2, 82.2, 18.1, 81.9, 56.9, -274.45])
    ...: b = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7])
    ...: 

# After code run ...

In [97]: b
Out[97]: array([ 0, -1,  2,  3,  4, -1, -1, -1])
```

---

**Approach #2 :** Less memory intensive approach

```
import pandas as pd 

def set_mask(a,b,thresh):
    a_b = a[b]
    N = len(a_b)
    sidx = a_b.argsort()
    sorted_a_b = a_b[sidx]

    mask0 = sorted_a_b[1:] - sorted_a_b[:-1]  < thresh    
    id_arr = np.zeros(N, dtype=int)
    id_arr[np.flatnonzero(~mask0)+1] = 1

    ids = id_arr.cumsum()
    d = np.column_stack(( ids, sidx))

    df0 = pd.DataFrame(d, columns=(('ids','sidx')))
    pp = df0['sidx'].groupby([ids]).min()

    maskc = np.ones(N,dtype=bool)
    maskc[pp.values] = 0
    return maskc
```

Use this mask to replace the `mask` needed at the last step from previous approach.

Comment: @qw_ You said you have implemented the solution to this with 2 nested loops. Could you share that? We could use it against this posted solution of mine for verification

Comment: @qw_ Well first off, I was asking for the code ( 2 nested loops code). Secondly, the before and after that you showed, are those for `a` or `b`? The `b` values that I am getting upon running [`this code`](https://github.com/aiwprton/test/blob/master/z.py) for `b` are between `800` and `1000`.

Comment: @qw_ We were needed to index into `a` with `b`. Should be fixed in the latest edits. Check it out. Also, please add those nested loops code into the question for clarity.

Comment: @qw What's the length of `b` array that you timed it on?

Comment: @qw_ Broadcasting takes the loop complexity down to `C` level. We can't measure its complexity at Python level, but should be much lesser than a corresponding loop at Python level. Its slowing down because of the memory requirements as also stated in the answer post.